# D3 - Paths with negative values

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, charts, data-visualization

I am trying to make a chart in D3 (that looks like the screenshot below) with triangles that point up when the value is positive and down when the value is negative.

[image]

I'm creating the triangles using a custom 'd' attribute. I am able to make the green (positive) triangles, but can't seem to figure out how to make the red ones point downward correctly.

I've been able to get it to work as rectangles using this: http://jsfiddle.net/pYZn8/16/, but not as paths. Haven't been able to find much on negative paths.

Any suggestions? I have attached a fiddle below. Thanks!

https://jsfiddle.net/zkbu31sm/

```
var margin = {top: 50, right: 40, bottom: 60, left: 10},
      containerWidth = $('.research-section4-graph').width();  

  var width = containerWidth - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 700 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var data = [
    {sector : 1, val : 53},
    {sector : 1, val : -40},
    {sector : 2, val : 19},
    {sector : 2, val : -39},
    {sector : 3, val : 45},
    {sector : 3, val : -23},
    {sector : 4, val : 45},
    {sector : 4, val : -26},
    {sector : 5, val : 54},
    {sector : 5, val : -40},
    {sector : 6, val : 25},
    {sector : 6, val : -34},
  ];

  data.forEach( function(d) { 
    d.val = +d.val; 
  });

  var allSectors = d3.set( data.map( function(d) { return d.sector; } ) ).values();

  var yScale = d3.scale
                 .linear()
                 .domain( [d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.val; }), d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.val; })] )
                 .range( [height, 0] );

  var xScale = d3.scale
                 .ordinal()
                 .domain( allSectors )
                 .rangeBands( [0, width], .5);

  var xAxis = d3.svg
                .axis()
                .scale(xScale)
                .tickSize( height )
                .orient('bottom');

  var svg = d3.select('.research-section4-graph')
              .append('svg')
              .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
              .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
              .append('g')
              .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

  var xAxisGroup = svg.append('g')
                      .attr('class', 'x axis')
                      .call(xAxis);

  xAxisGroup.selectAll('line')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (xScale.rangeBand() / 1) + ', 0)' );

  var triangleGroup = svg.selectAll('.triangle-group')
                    .data(data)
                    .enter()
                    .append('g')
                    .attr('class', 'triangle-group');

  var triangle = triangleGroup.append('path')
                              .attr('d', function(d) {
                                return 'M ' + xScale(d.sector) + ' ' + yScale(0) + ' L ' + (xScale(d.sector) + (xScale.rangeBand() / 2)) + ' ' + yScale(0) + ' L ' + (xScale(d.sector) + xScale.rangeBand()) + ' ' + yScale(0) + ' Z';
                              })
                              .attr('class', function(d) {
                                return d.val > 0 ? 'triangle positive' : 'triangle negative';
                              });

  triangle.transition().duration(1000)
          .attr('d', function(d) {
            return 'M ' + xScale(d.sector) + ' ' + yScale(0) + ' L ' + (xScale(d.sector) + (xScale.rangeBand() / 2)) + ' ' + yScale( Math.max(0, d.val) ) + ' L ' + (xScale(d.sector) + xScale.rangeBand()) + ' ' + yScale(0) + ' Z';
          });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `transition` setting:

```
yScale( Math.max(0, d.val)
```

When the d.val is negative value, yScale will use yScale(0) as the drawing point, which is why the path is not visible since there is no available 'negative' position value. Change it to `yScale(d.val)` works. Plunkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/JH5VUAGICdhX56TRISj1?p=preview)